# (C) Using while(fscanf(fptr,"%[^\n] %d %f",nome,&regAlmoxarifado,&preco) != EOF) locks the program into a loop

Tags: c

I have a file with the following contents:

```
lucas lucas lucas
24121 23.00
popotao popotao
2525252 23.52
yee yee
2442421 12.00
```

I have to read all the words and store them all in a single string, then the number into a int and the last number into a float. It works just fine if I just use "`%s %d %f`", except the `%s` only pulls the word until it finds a space, meaning it prints in the console like this:

```
lucas 0 0.00
lucas 0 0.00
lucas 24121 23.00
popotao 24121 23.00
popotao 2525252 23.52
yee 2525252 23.52
yee 2442421 12.00
```

So I tried using `%[^\n]` (and a few variations such as `[^\t\n]` and `[^\t\n]s`, `\t` isn't making a difference and putting an `s` at the end just breaks the program further), and it kind of worked for the first 3 values (lucas lucas lucas into the string, 24121 into the int and 23.00 into the float), but then it just keeps printing those same 3 values over and over forever, like this:

```
lucas lucas lucas 24121 23.00
lucas lucas lucas 24121 23.00
lucas lucas lucas 24121 23.00
lucas lucas lucas 24121 23.00
lucas lucas lucas 24121 23.00
lucas lucas lucas 24121 23.00
lucas lucas lucas 24121 23.00
```

It doesn't read the following contents nor does the program end, I honestly have no clue what is the problem, using the debug tool the variables "nome,regAlmoxarifado,preco" just stay with the same value while going through fscanf. Here's the actual code, any help is welcome:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    FILE *fptr;
    char nome[20];
    int regAlmoxarifado;
    float preco;
    fptr = fopen("Estoque.txt","r");
    
    while(fscanf(fptr,"%[^\n] %d %f",nome,&regAlmoxarifado,&preco) != EOF)
        printf("%s %d %.2f\n",nome,regAlmoxarifado,preco);
        
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you read each line with `fgets()` and apply `sscanf()` to it. If the lines don't all have the same format, try the formats one by one, until you find the one that works. Try the hardest-to-fit first. So you would try `%s%s` for two strings, last.

Comment: I recommend that you use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read lines instead. And that you read all input as lines, then use `sscanf` to parse the line.

Comment: OT:  regarding:  `fptr = fopen("Estoque.txt","r");`  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.   If not successful (==NULL) then call `perror( "fopen to read Estoque.txt failed" );`  followed by: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: OT: regarding: `fscanf(fptr,"%[^\n] %d %f`  1) the first format conversion specifier is for a field of 20 characters and %[] always appends a NUL byte to the input.  Therefore, to avoid any possibility of a buffer overflow there needs to be a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer.  Much better to check for success rather than EOF.  Suggest `while(fscanf(fptr,"%19[^\n] %d %f",nome, &regAlmoxarifado, &preco) == 3 )`

Answer (score 2):

Put a space at the beginning of the format string so it will skip over whitespace before it starts looking for the words. Otherwise it fails because the next character after the two numbers is a newline, and `%[^\n]` fails.

And instead of comparing to `EOF`, compare to 3, which is the number of elements you expect it to scan. That way you won't get into an infinite loop when parsing fails.

```
    while(fscanf(fptr," %[^\n] %d %f",nome,&regAlmoxarifado,&preco) == 3)
```

Comment: @Barmer, i just replaced OPs `while` statement with your `while` statement , but nothing gets printed on screen.

Comment: Oops, `!=` should be `==` now.

Comment: @Barmar thank you, this worked, such a simple fix lol. However, changing it to 3 doesn't work for my purpose, the idea is that this file reads from another file which records names, they can have 1, 2, 3 or however many words a name can have, it isn't always the same ammount. But thank you for the suggestion, I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: It's not counting the number of words. It's counting the number of items that were extracted from the input. All the words extracted by `%[^\n]` just count as 1 item.

Comment: So it's 1 line + 2 floats = 3.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
while(fscanf(fptr,"%[^\n] %d %f",nome,&regAlmoxarifado,&preco) != EOF)
```

with

```
while(fscanf(fptr," %19[^0-9] %d %f",nome,&regAlmoxarifado,&preco) == 3)
```

The space before the `%19[` to consume the trailing new line lefted by the previous scan.

`19` to be protected from buffer overflows (the length of the string is 20 including the final `'\0'`).

`^0-9` reads until a digit is found.

Compare with `== 3` instead of `!= EOF` in order to skip malformed lines.

Or better yet, use `fgets` and the functions provided in `string.h`. `scanf` is always a bad option:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *file;
    char str[128];
    long reg;
    double pre;

    file = fopen("Estoque.txt","r");
    while (fgets(str, sizeof str, file))
    {
        size_t pos;

        if ((pos = strcspn(str, "0123456789")) > 0) // Position of the first digit
        {
            str[pos - 1] = '\0'; // Cut the string
        }

        char *ptr;

        reg = strtol(str + pos, &ptr, 10); // 10 means base 10
        pre = strtod(ptr, NULL);
        printf("%s %ld %.2f\n", str, reg, pre);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I always wonder, when we have better way to read strings using `fgets`, why these escape characters are introduced. I see most of the people are using that way to read multi word strings

Comment: @csavvy Many beginners think of `scanf` as a general purpose input parser, even though it's not really as useful as they expect.